# Set 2 buttons to same action

Tags: dota-2

I wanted to use two buttons for the same action (Stop - S and Mouse 4), but I cannot find any setting to do so.

Can someone point me on how to do so?

Comment: Try to edit the config file manually ?

Comment: I've edited the config.cfg manually, but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`config.cfg` is automatically generated, so it will lose any edits you make to it.

To set up custom actions for buttons you need to edit this file (you may need to create it first):
`steamapps/dota 2[ beta]/dota/cfg/autoexec.cfg`

To bind both `S` and `MOUSE4` to *Stop*, write the following lines to `autoexec`.

```
bind S "dota_stop"
bind MOUSE4 "dota_stop"
```

Note that the in-game keyboard settings override the settings in `autoexec`, so you may need to clear the action there. Also, those custom settings are not synchronized to Steam Cloud.

---

In case someone needs to do the opposite – make a button execute many actions at the same time: just separate them with semicolons.

For example, you can make a button to toggle autocast no matter which skill slot it is in:

```
bind T "dota_ability_autocast 0; dota_ability_autocast 1; dota_ability_autocast 2; dota_ability_autocast 3"
```

Comment: Note: autoexec.cfg didn't exist, so I created it, and put the two lines in it (well, with bind "s" "dota_stop" instead, as in the config.cfg). It now works as I want it to, thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this VAC-safe, though?

Comment: @RenoYeo Why wouldn't it be safe if it's part of the game

Comment: just asking. well, that's that.