# How can I set it up so I can use a single key for multiple functions?

Tags: dota-2

I want to set it so that my D key does ability 4, and also inventory 3, and my F key does ability 5, and also inventory 4. And respectively to do "take and retrieve items" on courier.

When I try to set D to ability 4, it will stay as take on crow, and F on ability 5 will stay as retrieve, but when I put D and F on inventory 3 and 4, it'll take D and F off of everything else, and only be used for the item slots. I plan on just not using slots 3 and 4 with active items on heroes with 4th and 5th abilities, such as doom, and I know it's possible because I've seen Sing Sing do it on Rubick, and he had D set on a Inventory slot for an item, as well as his stolen skill.

Comment: I assure you that you don't want to do this. You can turn off mirorring of abilities between courier and heroes if you'd like, go to Controls-->Abilities-->Courier.

Comment: What you're looking for is called a macro. Some keyboards come with this built-in. If you don't have a keyboard that has that, you will need to look for a program that does that for you.

Comment: @close voter: that "duplicate" is literally the exact opposite of what the asker wants...

Comment: i'm not looking for a macro. Schism gets what i'm saying. i'm looking for one button to do 2 things. i dont want one button to ACTIVATE two things that'd b a macro. i want my d to b my item 3. and f to be item for. because most people dont hav a 4th and 5th ability, and only hav the first 3 then ultimate. BUT ont he occasion that i play 5 or 6 skilled heroes, i just want to be able to move the active items off the 3rd and 4th slots, so i only use d and f for the items instead. all the while, i'd like d and f to be take and retrieve on the courier

Comment: That actually is a macro what you describe. It has nothing to do with doing or activating. A macro is about helping you do multiple and/or repetitive tasks whether that is simultaneously, at random times or at specific time intervals. You might want to look into "autohotkey" at first it looks quite challenging but with a bit of reading it is very easy to setup.

Comment: Note, I just read the comment, there is no option within Dota 2 that would set your item to fgh for 4 skill heroes and sdf for 2 skill heroes, that just ain't possible from within the client.

Comment: i dont understand the question at all but if i take what anton roth commented: you can do 2 macros, 4spellhero.cfg and 2spellhero.cfg which he can load manually when the game starts. @DazzlingUnicorn: could u provide an actual example for me? like on key x i want item y + z (x y and z should become real names like bkb or what not because i dont get the scenario) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question, and you can find the answer for both setting multiple keys to one action and one key to multiple actions in there.

[Set 2 buttons to same action](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/116521/set-2-buttons-to-same-action)